# Public elements in interface implementation

Tags: c#, interface

I have this interface and a class implementing it:

```
interface Scraper
{
    string DateToUrl(DateTime date);
}

class ScraperA: Scraper
{
    string Scraper.DateToUrl(DateTime date)
    {
        return "some string based on date";
    }
}
```

I'd like to test it. I try to add this method to `ScraperA`:

```
    public void JustATest()
    {
        DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, 5, 31);
        string url = DateToUrl(date);
        Console.WriteLine(url);
    }
```

I put that in the class definition, but the compiler complains that it can't find `DateToUrl`. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By prefixing the method name with `Scraper` in the declaration you're [implementing the interface explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

This means that the method is essentially invisible unless it's called via the `Scraper` interface.

Your options:

1. Remove the `Scraper` prefix in the declaration. The method can then be called normally:

   ```
   public string DateToUrl(DateTime date)
   {
       return "some string based on date";
   }
   ```
2. Cast your instance to the interface before calling the method:

   ```
   public void JustATest()
   {
       DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, 5, 31);
       string url = ((Scraper)this).DateToUrl(date);
       Console.WriteLine(url);
   }
   ```

Comment: I went with the first option, but I had to make `DateToUrl` implementation public to make it work (because apparently interface methods are public by default).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "Scraper" part of "Scraper.DateToUrl":

```
interface Scraper
{
    string DateToUrl(DateTime date);
}

class ScraperA: Scraper
{
    string DateToUrl(DateTime date)
    {
        return "some string based on date";
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error that `ScraperA` doesn't implement all of the methods from its interface.

Comment: But it does.  Is there more to the interface or class that you're not showing us?